# Is it possible to continue after a fail in a chain?

Tags: promise, q

I have something like:

```
doHTTPRequest()
.then(handleSuccess, checkNotFound)
.then(uploadSomething)
.fail()
.done()
```

Now when I'm getting into checkNotFound I need to check if I got 404, if so it's not an actual fail and I want to continue with uploadSomething, but Q chaining directs me to fail.
On any other failure (e.g: any other status code) I do want to get into fail().

Comment: If it's not a fail then why are you putting it in the fail callback? Anyway, you can use `Q.always` that fires regardless.

Comment: Because doHTTPRequest() is a function not written by me that returns a Q promise and it fails the promise on 404. Can you please attach a quick code snippet with the Q.always?

Comment: The correct solution is not to do `.always` ( look at `Q.finally` in [the API reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) but instead to use a new promise. Wrap `doHTTPRequest` with a promise that fulfills in 404 or fulfillment of the promise.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Why is that "correct", and his current approach is not? I don't know about `Q`, but [`Bluebird`'s catch](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#catchfunction-handler---promise) returns a `Promise`

Comment: @Domi I have no idea what I wrote there it was more than a year ago :P I think the point of it is to make `doHTTPRequest` return a fulfulled promise on 404s, one way to accomplish that is to call `.catch` on the original request and handle the rejection with a fulfillment with a 404 value.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `then` is `promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` and it returns a new promise. The returned promises is resolved by whatever `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` returns or throws. That is to say, if you handle the error in `onRejected` and return a promise that fulfills, that will pass through to the result and skip your `fail` handler.  In code:

```
function request(url) {
    // returns a promise
}

function retryForeverLoop(url) {
    return request(url).then(null, function (error) {
        return retryForeverLoop(url);
    });
   // note that retrying forever might not work out well
}

retryForeverLoop(url)
.then(uploadSomething)
.done()
```

Comment: "note that retrying forever might not work out well" is a good point though I think I'm right in saying that this pattern avoids javascript's stack limit (~32000). If I'm right, and in the absence of an established term, we might call this 'dislocated recursion'. Of course, it could still be problematic for other reasons.

Comment: I think the better question is "does fail return a new promise", because that's the essence of continuing after a failure.

Answer (score 0):

This could work if the library errbacks with the request object.

```
doHTTPRequest()
.fail(function(request){
    if( request.isRequest && request.is404 ) {
        //This will propagate to the next .then
        return request;
    }
    else {
        //This will propagate to the next .fail
        throw request;
    }
})
.then(handleSuccess)
.then(uploadSomething)
.fail()
.done()
```

Btw the second argument to `.then` is almost entirely about promise library interop. In user code you should use the usually available, far more readable `.catch/.fail/.whatever` alternative which also avoids the pitfall mentioned here https://github.com/kriskowal/q/#handling-errors. If such alternative is not available, even then `.then(null, handler)` should be used instead of passing error and success in a same `.then` call.

The sync equivalent of above code is like:

```
try {
    try {
        var a = doHTTPRequest();
    }
    catch(request) {
        if( request.isRequest && request.is404 ) {
            a = request;
        }
        else {
            throw request;
        }
    }
    uploadSomething(handleSuccess(a));
}
catch( e ) {
    //This is the second .fail()
}
```